# Difficulties understanding variable reassignment in Lisp

Tags: variables, lisp

I'm facing some problems understanding the results of a few experiments with nconc.

```
(setf x '(a b c))
(setf y '(1 2 3))

(nconc x y) ; => x = (A B C 1 2 3), y = (1 2 3)
```

From what I've read, nconc changes the rest field of x to point to y.

```
(setf (nth 1 y) 10) ; => x = (A B C 1 10 3), y = (1 10 3)
```

So far, so good.

```
(setf y '(4 5 6)) ; => x = (A B C 1 10 3) y = (4 5 6)
```

Why does x still reference to the old cons cell, or in other words does the reassignment of y not just change the data at the address of y?

Thanks in advance
Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lisp variables don't point to fixed memory. They point to Lisp data objects. Setting a variable does not change any object memory. The variable just points to some other data.

Answer (score 2):

Because the last `cons` in `x` is set to pointing to the `cons` that `y` was pointing at. It doesn't point at `y`'s value dynamically or by reference.

```
(setf x '(a b c))
; x = (a b c)
(setf y '(1 2 3))
; x = (a b c)
; y = (1 2 3)
(nconc x y)
; x = (a b c 1 2 3)
; y = (1 2 3) = (nthcdr 3 x)
(setf (nth 1 y) 10)
; x = (a b c 1 10 3)
; y = (1 10 3) = (nthcdr 3 x)
(setf y '(4 5 6))
; x = (a b c 1 10 3)
; y = (4 5 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

nconc changes the rest field of x to point to the **value** of `y`. The **value** `y` is the cell, which y points to. If you move the `y` pointer to another target, the rest field of `x` won't change, and will still point to `(1 2 3)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (both of you) I think "if you move the pointer.. " got me in the right direction. If I understand correctly: setf on a symbol does not change existing data - even if the symbol already exists, but always creates a new memory location to store the value. Only setf to a cons cell will overwrite existing data in memory. Correct?

Comment: No, that's not quite right. Actually setf is change existing data. And in case `(setf x ...)` it changes the value of `x`, not `*x` (the value, pointed by x) in C-notation.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I meant - sorry my comment wasn't that clear. It sure changes the value of the 'pointer'.